# Grafana Agent to AMP

Tags: grafana, agent

I am using grafana agent and trying to send metrics to AMP - Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus.
using the agent.yaml below. Unfortunately, the metrics are not being received by the AMP namespace. Maybe i am doing something wrong.
Could anyone give me a hand ?

```
server:
  log_level: info

metrics:
  global:
    scrape_interval: 1m
    scrape_timeout: 30s
    remote_write:
      - url: https://aps-workspaces.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/workspaces/ws-.......-35c4-4028-....-f232a1ba0959/api/v1/remote_write
  configs:
    - name: default
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: agent
          static_configs:
            - targets: [127.0.0.1:9200']
integrations:
  node_exporter:
    enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `sigv4` authentication and correct IAM role with `aps:RemoteWrite` action. For example:

```
    remote_write:
      - sigv4:
            enabled: true
            region: ${REGION}
        url: ${REMOTE_WRITE_URL}
```

Check documentation of your agent version, because your version may need different syntax.